# How to associate a specific link with an app?

Tags: facebook, file-permissions, imo-instant-messenger

I'm trying to use imo messenger to access my facebook chat. I remember I've been able to do it in the past but now I can't do it anymore.

In the past, I loged on facebook through imo and then the facebook app opened, and then I could access facebook chat through Imo.

Now when I log in imo, it opens the browser with a unusual kind of link - A kind of token. How can I open this token with the facebook app? I've read some stuff about how to associate files, but I've found nothing about these token links.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely up to the app what links to handle. If the Facebook app isn't written to handle the "unusual kind of link" you describe, you can't make it handle it.

Comment: But what's the source of this information? It is so because you've never seen it happen or do you have some official reference that says so?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Any Android developer could tell you the same thing.

Comment: Well, that's not entirely true... https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=qD4PVdTAEob_8QWGuYDQBA&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app&ved=0CCIQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNEddguEsP9-HkLGt5QRKuc6I5VSjg

Comment: @Madivad I don't understand the relevance of your link. It's explaining how the app author can open the link in their own app. As I said, this is something the app can do, but not something you can do yourself.